# Laravel mailable, data not being passed to Blade when implements ShouldQueue

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Im trying to send an email, with ShouldQueue, and passing data into the email blade view, but it fails if i implement ShouldQueue.

See below for my code.
The code as it is below, does execute the mail and places it in jobs queue (database driver). It works and i can see the job in jobs table.

Then i run **php artisan queue:work** to start worker on my computer.
When worker tries to execute job, it fails. It is now removed from jobs table and new entry to failed_jobs table. The email is not sent.

In failed_jobs table, exception column, i get this error (stacktrace removed)

> Next Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException: Undefined variable $data (View: /Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/resources/views/mails/ContactForm.blade.php) in /Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/resources/views/mails/ContactForm.blade.php:2

**IF I remove "implements ShouldQueue" from the ContactFormMail class, everything works and email is being sent, but then, the email is not being put in the queue.**

I have tried passing data both ways described in [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#view-data) and i have also tried restarting worker.

Any ideas where i go wrong?
If it was not clear, I want to pass data to ContactForm.blade.php and also place email in queue.

**Here is my code**

Controller:

```
public function submit()
{
    $this->validate();

    $data = [
        'name' => $this->name,
        'email' => $this->email,
        'message' => $this->message,
    ];

    try {

        Mail::to('xxx@xxx.xx')->send(new ContactFormMail($data) );

        $this->name = "";
        $this->email = "";
        $this->message = "";

        $this->status = "Message sent!";

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        $this->status = "Something went wrong!";

    }

}
```

ContactFormMail class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ContactFormMail extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{

    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    /**
    * Create a new message instance.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
    * Build the message.
    *
    * @return $this
    */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('mails.ContactForm');
    }
}
```

ContactForm blade file:

```
<div>
    {{$data['name']}}<br>
    {{$data['email']}}<br>
    {{$data['message']}}<br>
</div>
```

Comment: markdown instead of view         return $this->markdown('mails.ContactForm')->subject('your mail subject');

Answer (score 0):

Please try restarting the queue worker. Probably something got stuck. After restarting the queue it "should" work.

`php artisan queue:restart`

Comment: I have tried restarting worker, restarted terminal window and reboot mac. Nothing helps.